# C++ Binary Tree Traversal Inorder, Preorder and Postorder

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder, preorder

I'm currently working on a C++ project and part of it is to traverse the binary tree using inorder, preorder, and postorder.

```
class TNode
{
  public:
  int val;
  TNode() {}
  TNode(int v) { val = v; }
  TNode * left;
  TNode * right;
  TNode * parent;
};

class BTree
{
  void print_pre_order(TNode *r);// print the node as you traverse according to the order.
  void print_in_order();
  void print_post_order();
}


BTree::BTree()
{
  root = new TNode(1);
  root->parent = 0;
  root->left = new TNode(2);
  root->right = new TNode(3);
  root->left->left = new TNode(4);
  root->left->right = new TNode (5);
  root->right->left = new TNode(6);
}
void BTree::print_pre_order(TNode *r)
{
  if (r == 0)
  {
      return;
  }
  cout << r->val;
  print_pre_order(r->left);
  print_pre_order(r->right);
} 

int main()
{
  BTree y;
  y.print_pre_order(y.root);
  return 0;
}
```

In my default constructor, I've initialized values for some nodes, but when I run the code, the output I'm getting is "124" and gets an error. I don't know where I did wrong, can someone help?

Comment: Define BTree member variable root and initialize in BTree() contructor, populate Btree with nodes before traversal. Program is very incomplete.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Since I'm using Visual Studio, it only says "the program has stoped working" @smac89

Comment: Amazing you got that far. `class BTree` doesn't seem to have a `BTree::BTree()` or any of the used member variables.

Comment: I was just want to print out all the elements in the tree to see if print_pre_order function works @seccpur

Comment: @user4581301 This is just part of the class BTree, there are many funcitons but I just didn't include them here. It has a default constructor, copy, and destructor..

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: It's not possible to help you if you don't have a description of what the problem is or where it is. Your program also doesn't compile as it is. I suggest you copy your program and try running it using an online compiler such as [`wandbox`](https://wandbox.org/). You will be better at debugging your code if you can actually understand where your errors are coming from. Leave VS for now, get a compiler and a good text editor, and you won't regret it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no signs that the program ever sets any any pointers to zero, so `if (r == 0)` is unlikely to ever trigger an exit.

Give this a try:

```
class TNode
{
  public:
  int val;
  TNode(): val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}
  TNode(int v): val(v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}
  TNode * left;
  TNode * right;
  TNode * parent;
};
```

The `:` tells the compiler that a [member  initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) is coming. After that the code initializes all of the pointer members to point at null.

Change the

```
if (r == 0)
```

to

```
if (r == nullptr)
```

to better convey intent and you should be good to go.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! The code is working ! Thanks again. @user4581301